# What sort of RSA private key format is this and how are they generared

Tags: rsa, x.509

I am used to seeing a regular private key, with the standard key block, but I just came across this type which carries extra information as you can see. What format is this and how are these generated (openssl CLI syntax)?

- if not obvious, `<snip>` is  my way of just reducing the size for easier reading.

```
Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: RSA
    Key Security Level: High (3072 bits)

modulus:
    00:d5:1a:d1:1e:1e:25:0e:70:9c:34:dc:49:04:1c:78
    <snip>
    b7:

public exponent:
    01:00:01:

private exponent:
    00:b7:1b:ab:c3:ad:33:3a:0d:18:ab:72:fc:6a:43:ec
    <snip>
    81:

prime1:
    00:d6:d0:2f:95:b1:3f:33:35:f7:f7:52:3c:c1:a4:52
    <snip>
    39:

prime2:
    <snip>
    f0:28:45:e5:7c:41:41:4a:e5:0e:bc:9f:6f:a8:10:5c
    6f:

coefficient:
    <snip>
    43:7a:c8:13:bd:68:92:be:73:25:30:2f:96:47:4d:84
    

exp1:
    7c:c9:6d:8b:20:ef:1c:d9:b2:15:8b:41:5e:20:0e:26
    <snip>


exp2:
    <snip>
    87:64:0d:2c:85:48:9e:90:17:f3:7c:ef:a4:37:ff:f5


Public Key PIN:
    pin-sha256:BKhVmaG9E0fMyBvVzuYbAHBezlvd7CxlF01wvtDdc0Y=
Public Key ID:
    sha256:04a85599a1bd1347ccc81bd5cee61b00705ece5bddec2c65174d70bed0dd7346
    sha1:ebe2a85eb1bc413e57c30a08f6af9acc2c1441b5

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIG4wIBAAKCAYEA1RrRHh4lDnCcNNxJBBx4satUlsqqKu6mBUObRqEZ125cOq7E
<snip>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most popular RSA key format](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57043/most-popular-rsa-key-format). Also [Differences between “BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY” and “BEGIN PRIVATE KEY”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/), [Is there a specification for the “BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY” format?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/).

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured this out. Its from a standard ASN.1 structured RSA key. Turns out these extra components are built in and the following extras them.

`openssl rsa -text -in priv.key`

A breakdown here: https://etherhack.co.uk/asymmetric/docs/rsa_key_breakdown.html